# Why are both channels heard at the same time when selecting left or right?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones

I have been running Ubuntu 16.04 for years without a problem, and just recently after the last update it is mixing both channels together. I am running it on a Mac Powerbook with 16 Gigs of RAM, and 256 Gig SSD drive. I have never seen this problem before and have already reloaded alsa base pulseaudio to at first no effect, and now it will not connect with the blue tooth external speaker. The right and left channels are fine on internal speakers, and moving the slider changes the volume correctly. When that is tried on the earbuds plugged into the headphone jack (apple earbuds I had no problems with before), when the slider is on the left side, the sound comes out of both, with the left coming out of both earbuds. The same happens when the slider goes to the right side. When in the middle, a distortion is heard.Question: is it the internal sound card in the laptop, or software? And if it is software, how do I fix it? If I upgrade to a more recent release, with that fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 16.04 is now EOL

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm